# Writing a todo list in C. Having a lot of problems

Tags: c

I'm still learning, so if I'm doing something **really** inefficient, tell me. Otherwise, I care more about why this isn't working more.

There's no way I can have it write multiple words unless I use quotations. Is there a way I can make it write multiple words with me not having to add quotations?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main() {

    char str[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(".todo","a");

    printf("\n\nTODO list\n\n");
        printf("~ ");
        scanf("%s", str);
        fprintf(f,str);
        fprintf(f,"\n");
        fclose(f);
}
```

I did decide to make a loop so I can write multiple things. This is what I did:

```
for(;;) {
    printf("~ ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    if(str == "break") {
        fclose(f);
        printf("\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(f,str);
}
```

However, if I type "break", it does not exit. It does not write to .todo (which I assume is because fclose is not being ran) How can I make it exit, if not that way?

Comment: if you are reading strings, don't use scanf to read from the keyboard, use fgets instead (e.g. char buffer[128]; fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin)), just remove the last character (\n)

Comment: Don't pass a non-literal string to the format parameter of the printf family of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just compare the string with some predefined value say "break". So when user enters break, you can break out of the loop using strcmp

```
for(;;) {
  printf("~ ");
  scanf("%s", str);
  if(strcmp(str,"break")==0) {
    fclose(f);
    printf("\n");
    break;
  }
  fprintf(f,str);
}
```

Other method is to use `fgets`, `getch()` or `getchar()` to check for blank lines or just `enter` as input and break out

Comment: yes, thank you. However; I still have the problem of not able to write multiple words. Do you know how I could write multiple words without having to use quotations?

Comment: @user2888419 : yes use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) for storing multiple words, its also might be possible with scanf using scanf("%[^\t\n]",str);

Comment: Have another problem. I'm using `fgets(str,256,stdin)`. However, it does not break when I type `break`. Everything else is the same though. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @user2888419 this would be because fgets also stores \n at the end, you need to remove it before comparing

Answer (score 1):

```
if(str == "break")
```

This won't work in C. To compare strings you need to use the `strcmp` or `strncmp` library functions.

Have a look here to see how it works, what it returns, etc.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp